# Allow HTTPD service to create folders and make changes in the files

Tags: linux, webserver

I am running drupal on a host, the problem is it can not create directories or update files. I have tried to apply the 775 permissions to all the folders but still the problem is not solved.

After doing a little research I have came to the conclusion that the HTTPD service should be allowed to perform sudo tasks. Is there a way to allow the service to do the tasks that require the sudo permissions?

I am running a UBUNTU server.

Comment: Please stop what you're doing right now. Take a deep breath. Then think about the possible security implications of making all your folders world writable. **DO NOT** run Apache (`httpd`) as root. You are making incorrect assumptions. You need to learn a bit about how the system works before you proceed. Start [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-HOWTO/file-security.html).

Comment: @allquixotic: I would read that, but how should I tackle the issue, so that the websites are secure and the scripts can create files and folders?

Comment: I don't know what you googled but letting httpd perform sudo tasks is a really bad idea. Mostly the problem you have occurs when you upload files via ftp with i. e. user `abc` which belongs to group `def`, but apache runs as user and group `www-data`. Drupal being a PHP-Application also has some limitations. Just search in google for Apache and PHP-Tutorials. The website from @allquixotic mentioned is also a good idea to read, but is just basic knowledge (which is not bad at all) for your problem.

Comment: Drupal should only need write access to a certain folder path. Somewhere in Drupal's configuration files, it will list that path, which is configurable (you can set it to whatever you want). All you need to do is figure out what user your `httpd` is running under, then set the owner of the folder(s) that Drupal writes to, to the same user that `httpd` runs under. Then set the permissions of the applicable folder(s) to 775 (the third number doesn't need to be 5; it would probably be OK as 0, even, which denies access to those who are not the owner user/group).

Comment: I don't actually know much about Drupal except that it's a PHP application and apparently running on top of Apache in your configuration, so I don't know where to point you to the configuration file or the folder where it would be trying to write. You need to figure that out for yourself. Then pay attention to the user and group that owns the folder, and the user and group that apache httpd runs under, and make sure the two match up. **Don't** try setting all folders under `/` or `/usr` to be owned by `www-data`; you will brick your system!

Comment: Follow the "principle of least privilege", which means, give as little permission as possible. Setting recursive `775` permissions on a big directory like `/usr` or `/var/www` is a bad idea. You should probably attempt to undo the damage you did first. And *never* run a daemon under root, unless the software developer explicitly tells you to do so (like the X server).

Comment: i think i should also read about user and user groups to understand what actually is happening.

Comment: Yes, definitely read up on users and groups.